# Start interactive application from IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, interactive

In a project we have a WCF Service which is hosted in IIS.
Now we need to start a windows application (interactive, hence has a window).

Just to clarify: The application shall run on the server. It is a third party application we have no access to and cannot modify it.

The WCF Service leverages an application pool that runs under a special user account, "load user profile" is checked.

I still get the System.ComponentModel Access violation exception, so I think that I missed something.

Also have seen solutions with the "IIS Admin Services" which can allow desktop interaction, but this seems to belong to IIS 6 only.

Comment: @Downvoter: Any comment?

Comment: Check to make sure that the account you are using can read and write the correct registry keys, and file locations.  Make sure that the file you are attempting to execute is in a location on disk that can be accessed by the service account.

Comment: @RoyFolkker Worked. Thank you! Provide it as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Hi, I have similar issue. I implemented OpenID connect in my asp.net web form using MSAL. It works fine when tested locally in VS. But when it is hosted in IIS  I am getting error below. Any idea on resolving???

"Error occurred while accessing inbox. Description: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that the account you are using can read and write the correct registry keys, and file locations. Make sure that the file you are attempting to execute is in a location on disk that can be accessed by the service account.